# Relation between the display of Notification and foreground Service life cycle

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground-service

In my app I made a service to the foreground and display a notification to the user. By `notification.setAutoCancel(false);` I set the notification icon always displayed without auto-cancel itself.

Actually I need this service run long period of time and I want to make the user be aware of this(by seeing the notification icon they know the service is still running).

So I wonder whether my hypothesis is correct, **as long as the notification icon is displayed, it means the service is still running, and once the notification icon is gone, that means the service is done for some reasons.**

Here is the simplified code:

```
LongLiveService extends Service{
    private MyThread thread;

    onStartCommand() {
        thread.start();
        createNotification(this);
    }

    createNotification(Context context) {
        // build a notification
        notification.setAutoCancel(false);
        startForeground.invoke(this, notificationID, notification.build());
    }
}


MyThread extends Thread{
    run() {
        // doing something all the time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> once the notification icon is gone, that means the service is done for some reasons.

If you want your notification to stay in the status bar as long as the `Service` is running, you need to make the notification persistent via the flag `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`, so it can't be dismissed:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(...);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(..., Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);        
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(..., pendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I use `PendingIntent.getActivity(... , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` and till now this works fine, so what's the difference between `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`, I have read the google document and it's confusing.